# Using CloudWatch Metric Filter to report memory consumption percentage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have wide use of AWS Lambda as part of our infrastructure.
To gain better visibility, I'd like to be able to report a custom CloudWatch metric which value is memory_used/memory_allocated, this can be achieved using CloudWatch logs and metric filter.

Consider the following log message:

```
REPORT RequestId: de96230a-70c1-491f-97f5-f76805227173  Duration: 811.71 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 122 MB
```

For the above message the calculated value for the metric should be `122/256=0.476`.

At the time, I couldn't overcome the [metric filter syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html).
Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly with one metric filter. You could do something like this:

#### 1. Extract MemorySize and MaxMemoryUsed into 2 separate metrics

Create 2 metric filters, both with the same rule `[type=REPORT, ...]`.
This will filter out lines that start with REPORT and it will create variables for each column of the line. In this case, it will create variables `$type, $2, $3, ...` up to `$19` (there are 19 space-separated words in the logline).

Values you need are in variables `$13` and `$18`, so when creating the 2 metric filters, use `$13` for the first metric and `$18` for the second metric in the *Metric value* field. Metric names and namespace can be whatever you want. I'll use `MemorySize` and `MaxMemoryUsed` for names and `CustomLambdaMetrics` as the namespace.

#### 2. Use metric math to calculate the value you need.

Now that you have the 2 metrics, you can create a widget with a source like this to get the average usage (region may be different in your case):

```
{
    "metrics": [
        [ { "expression": "m2/m1", "label": "Average memory usage", "id": "e1" } ],
        [ "CustomLambdaMetrics", "MemorySize", { "id": "m1", "visible": false } ],
        [ ".", "MaxMemoryUsed", { "id": "m2", "visible": false } ]
    ],
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "stat": "Sum",
    "period": 60
}
```

See here for more info on metric math: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm familiar with metric math. I wanted to avoid the usage of the numbered values, instead I think we can use 

[ report_label="REPORT", ..., label="Used:", max_memory_used_value, unit="MB" ]

However this doesn't work for the allocated memory size for some reason.

Comment: Doesn't work because you have three dots in the middle, so it will match only the last occurrence in the line. Also, lambda could append more stuff to the end of the line, like `Init Duration: ` for the first execution after lambda goes to sleep. That's why the numbered values are your best bet here.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid using 2 metrics for this but I guess the platform limitations dictate just that. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: > because you have three dots in the middle, so it will _match only the last occurrence in the line_

Arrrgh! That fine detail would be nice in the docs :)

Comment: Thanks that helps already! Is there any way of doing that only for the Init Duration?