# How to create CloudWatch alarm for memory usage on lambda based on CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the below log in CloudWatch and would like to create an alarm when average of Max memory usage exceeds 400 MB.

REPORT RequestId: xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx    Duration: 5750.91 ms    Billed Duration: 5751 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 150 MB Init Duration: 1562.14 ms

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? What exactly are you trying to do and what exactly are you asking? What have you already tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Memory Used** is not one of the standard [AWS Lambda function metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html) collected by Amazon CloudWatch.

You would need to:

- [Create metrics from log events using filters - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) to parse that log
- Configure the filter to find that output line and extract the "Memory Used" figure
- Use that extracted figure to populate a new CloudWatch metric
- Create an Alarm on that metric

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks John..!! Was looking for something other than the option you mentioned. Now achieved the outcome by creating  Custom metric filter.

Comment: Great! Feel free to Add an Answer describing what you did, to help future readers.

Comment: Referred this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543001/using-cloudwatch-metric-filter-to-report-memory-consumption-percentage